# How to write junit test for struts 2 action class?

Tags: struts2, junit4

I want to write the junit test for struts 2 action class methods.How to write test case for addUser function?
My action class look like this

```
puble class UserAction{

public String addUser(){
User user = new User();
user.setUserName("user");
user.setPassword("password");
UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO()
userDAO.addUser(user)
return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Struts 2 provides a JUnit plugin library that makes it easier to develop unit tests for testing your Struts 2 action classes. to test your action you need to know which aspect action class required in order to run .
you can check this example

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you're forced to write an integration test since you've hard-coded a DAO implementation. (There are ways around this, but writing better actions is a better approach.)

Instead of using an explicit DAO implementation, inject one. To unit test this action you'd want to simulate both the success and failure of adding the user.

Then check the action's return value.